# plotshape doesn't plot on correct candlestick

Tags: pine-script

I have written an indicator in pinescript and it doesn't work as expected. The idea is to make it plot a shape at a bar when price crosses over a moving average on the lower timeframe but only if price has crossed the same period moving average on a higher timeframe. A better explanation on what I try to achieve: let's say price is above the 5-period-SMA from 1h timeframe, and while it is above, at some point price will cross above the 5-period-SMA on 15m timeframe, and right then it should plot a shape on that bar on 15m timeframe. Who can help me? Here is the code:

```
study("MA Cross MTF Alert", shorttitle="MA Cross MTF Alert", overlay=true)

smaPeriod = input(5, title="Period SMA")
pricetype = input(close, title="Price Source For The SMA")
lowerTfRes = input(title="Lower timeframe", type=resolution, defval="15")
higherTfRes = input(title="Higher timeframe", type=resolution, defval="60")

priceLowTf = security(tickerid, lowerTfRes, pricetype)
priceHighTf = security(tickerid, higherTfRes, pricetype)

smaLowTf = sma(priceLowTf, smaPeriod)
smaHighTf = sma(priceHighTf, smaPeriod)

Buy =  close > smaLowTf and close > smaHighTf
Sell = close < smaLowTf and close < smaHighTf
plotshape(Buy, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=green)
plotshape(Sell, style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=red)
alertcondition(Buy, title="Buy alert", message="Buy " + syminfo.root + "MA Cross alert")
alertcondition(Sell, title="Sell alert", message="Sell " + syminfo.root + "MA Cross alert")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to get data from a lower timeframe than the present chart. You could get data from two different higher timeframe charts but for simplicity's sake I used the current chart in this example.

```
//@version=4
study("MA Cross MTF Alert", shorttitle="MA Cross MTF Alert", overlay=true)

smaPeriod = input(5, title="Period SMA")
pricetype = input(close, title="Price Source For The SMA")
higherTfRes = input(title="Higher timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="60")

priceHighTf = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTfRes, pricetype[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
smaHighTf = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTfRes, sma(priceHighTf, smaPeriod)[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

smaLowTf = sma(close, smaPeriod)

Buy =  crossover(close, smaLowTf) and close > smaHighTf
Sell = crossunder(close, smaLowTf) and close < smaHighTf
plot(smaLowTf)
plot(smaHighTf, color=color.black, linewidth=2)
plotshape(Buy[1], style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(Sell[1], style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, size=size.small)
alertcondition(Buy[1], title="Buy alert", message="Buy {{syminfo.root }} MA Cross alert")
alertcondition(Sell[1], title="Sell alert", message="Sell {{ syminfo.root }} MA Cross alert")
```

Additionally you were pulling in the price from the higher timeframe and then applying an SMA on the present timeframe. So say your present timeframe is 15m, if you pull a price point from the 1h chart it will show the same price for four bars, meaning your present-chart SMA is being applied to that. 1 period of 1h is 4 periods of 15m. You want to plug the SMA directly into the security function in order to get accurate values from the 1 hour chart.

Note that I delayed the data and set lookahead in order to avoid repainting. I additionally added `[1]` for the plotshapes and alertconditions to make sure the data is confirmed.

I changed the Buy and Sell conditions to a `crossover`, `crossunder` on the present chart to prevent retriggering.

The priceHighTf isn't used, you could use it in your `Buy` and `Sell` conditions.

I added plots to show the SMAa. Adding plots as you create your script will help figure out issues more quickly. I set a size for the `plotshape` because they were very small by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It works great now. I have only one more question. Is it possible to make it plot a shape if price has crossed the moving average  from the lower timeframe just once (while the candlestick is still open)?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you mean plotting the shape while a candlestick is open, as in it may cross and become true, and then "uncross" as the candle updates and have it remain plotted. If that's what you mean, variables roll back on each tick update, but you could simulate the behavior by using high or low (depending on direction) instead of close. As if a high crosses something moving upward, a future update would not make it "uncross", unless that is the level it is crossing moves significantly. You essentially would want to use data sources that can't undo a condition.